# AWS EC2 instance becomes inaccessible via SSH after

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-vpc

Issue : after a given period of time (usually the time it takes for the initial status checks to complete) I can no longer access my EC2 instance via SSH. More specifically during the initial period, I have normal access to my instance via SSH, then it drops, and the machine becomes completely unreachable, even when trying to ping it.

I have double checked Security Group, VPC settings etc. but don't think that can be the issue as at one point in time I can access the machine.

The issue occurs on "vanilla" instances from very basic standard AMIs as well as with AMIs I run on other AWS accounts. I have tried various instance types / sizes, but the issue occurs again and again.

Any ideas welcome! Thanks in advance

Dan

Comment: Use the AWS EC2 web console check the CPU. For t2 instance , if process overload >  100% for 30 mins , you will be throttle to 25% of CPU. And worst, if you process peak to 25%, it will be unresponsive to your ssh.

Comment: Checked that; no peak in CPU usage; max attained 2.5%

Comment: Is it possible that you, yourself, are behind a firewall that for whatever reason, is shutting off access after a few minutes?  It seems unlikely, of course, but it seems similarly unlikely for official AMIs with no customization at all to exbibit such behavior.

Comment: try `telnet <your_ec2_ip>  22`,  see whether the system give you are connection.   Please take note that if you use Auto-assign IP, there is no guarantee you will get the same EC2 domain name or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can cause this. Specifically, if you're supplying user data during startup it could encounter an issue and eliminate your ability to SSH if it is modifying the file system and mounts or changing permissions.

If you can save the underlying system volume you can remount it and check /var/log/boot.log and /var/log/cloud-init-output.log

Comment: Yes maybe, but I'm really done now to trying the simplest AMI with no frills, and no changes to the instance itself.